# Can not set up ad-hoc network on win7

Tags: windows-7, ad-hoc-network

I try to create and ad-hoc network at a hotel on my work notebook. It goes fine until I click on "Create an ad hoc network". Then I get a popup saying:
"The policies on your network prevent the creation of ad hoc networks. For more information contact your system administrator."
Is there a workaround for this?

I tried Connectify, it did create a network, but the Android devices I tried stopped by "Getting IP Address..."

Comment: Is it a machine provided to you by your company ?They may have disabled it, else i suggest you check the group policies of your laptop

Comment: As @Shakehar  notes it is likely a GPO  At a command promt type gpresult /R to look at applied policies.  Or call your systewm admin for assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that machines on Active Directory domains (i.e., most enterprise clients) can't create ad-hoc networks or enable Internet Connection Sharing. At least, that's what seemed to be the case when I last researched if this could be done (about a year ago). For hotels, I generally just bring my own WiFi router.

Comment: What kind of router do you use?

Comment: An ASUS WL520-GU running DD-WRT. I got it for around $20-25 a few years ago. I'm sure there are similarly inexpensive routers you can get nowadays.